# Efficient methods for storing many similar arrays?

Tags: arrays, difference

Recently I was faced with having to store many 'versions' of an array in memory *(think of an undo system or changes to a file in version-control - but could apply elsewhere too)*.

In case this isn't clear:

- Arrays may be identical, share some data, or none at all.
- Elements may be added or removed an any point.
- The goal is to avoid storing an entirely new array when there are large sections of the array that are identical.
- For the purpose of this question, changes such as adding a number to each value can be ignored (treated as different data).

I've looked into writing my own solution, in principle this can be done fairly simply:

- divide the array into small *blocks*.
- if nothing changes, reuse the blocks in each new *version* of the array.
- if only one block changes, make a new block with changed data.
- retrieving an array can be done by allocating the memory, then filling it with the data from each block.

Things become more involved is when the array length changes or when the data is re-ordered.
Then it becomes a trade off for how much time its worth to spend searching for duplicate blocks *(in my case I hashed some data at the beginning of each block to help identify candidates to use)*.

I've got my implementation working *(and can link to it if its useful, though I rather avoid discussing my spesific code, since it distracts from the general case)*.

I suspect my own code could be improved (using tried-and-tested memory hashing & searching methods). Possibly I'm not using the right terms but I wasn't able to find information on this searching online.

---

So my questions are:

- Which methods are most efficient for recognizing and storing arrays that share *some* contiguous data?
- Are there known, working methods which are considered best-practice to solve this problem?

---

Update, wrote a small(ish) single file [library](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/array_store.c$1) and [tests](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/tests/gtests/blenlib/BLI_array_store_test.cc$10), as well as a [Python reference version](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/py-array-cow).

Comment: What are you storing in these arrays?

Comment: look for COW "copy on write".

Comment: @Schwernm, 3d geometry, and associated attributes (color, UV coordinates). However I'm not sure this is an important part of the question - the data could be uncompressed audio or even plain-text.